# How to slide down a jQuery slideToggle when scaling a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with my slideToggle function. Once pressed it opens up the way I need it to. But when I scale the browser to test the responsive flow to the site the slideToggle still stays active instead of sliding down. I tried a few functions but nothing seems to work. Below is the scrip I am using without the code to slide down when it hits a specific screen resoultion. How would I go about fixing this issue?

```
$('#more').click(function () {
     var open = $('header').is('.open');
$('#footerPanel')['slide' + (open ? 'Up' : 'Down')](400);
$('header').animate({
     bottom: (open ? '-' : '+') + '=120' }, 400, function () {
$('header').toggleClass('open');
     });
});
$('#menu').click(function () {
    if ($('header').is('.open')) {
    $('header')
        .removeClass('open')
        .animate({
        'bottom': "-=120"
    }, function () {
        var $footer = $('.activetoggle');

        if ($footer.length) 
            $footer
                .toggleClass('activetoggle footerButton')
                .text('Footer');
    });
    $('#footerPanel').slideUp(400);
}
});

 $('.footerButton').click(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
$this.toggleClass('footerButton');
if ($this.hasClass('footerButton')) {
    $this.text('Footer');
} else {
    $this.text('Close');
}
$(this).toggleClass('activetoggle');
});
```

**My Code**

http://jsfiddle.net/wyze/XqUp4/4/

Comment: What is your issue in provided jsFiddle??? I mean provide your failing attempt at least...

Comment: I need the div to slide back down when the browsers scales to a specific screen resolution. For example when I scale the browser to a 480 resolution I would like the panel to slide down so it does not display the content anymore @A. Wolff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works for you. I have added to check whether the width is 780(you can change it), when the panel to slide down. Try adding this in you fiddle and check if this works

```
$(window).resize(function(){ //check when window resize
if($(window).width() < 780){ // check when the window width is less than 780 
    if ($('header').is('.open')) { 
        $('header')
            .removeClass('open')
            .animate({
            'bottom': "-=120"                
        });
        $footer = $('.activetoggle');
        if ($footer.length) {
             $footer.toggleClass('activetoggle footerButton').text('Footer');
        }
        $('#footerPanel').slideToggle(400);
    }
}
});
```